# wx.Media volume reset problems

Tags: python, wxpython

Am working on a media player application using wx.Media but the big challenge that i am having is that the SetVolume(new_volume) of the media ctrl method is not working properly but it mutes the sound when the new_volume reaches to 0..

The new_volume is from a volume slider control. so what is the best strategy to handle this?

any sample code will be highly appreciated?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a really simple MP3 player using wx.media that I blogged about a while ago. It might help you figure this out: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/

There's also a cool 3rd party widget that wraps mplayer that I used too: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/

It's more complicated, but it plays video back more reliably. Anyway, hopefully those will get you started at least.